# How to get values in nuxt.config.js, globally?

Tags: nuxt.js

Given a Nuxt project, how to get values from inside `nuxt.config.js`, globally?

For example...

**nuxt.config.js**

```
    myObject: {
        myString: 'hello!'
    },
```

**myVueComponent.vue**

Looking for a convenient way to get Nuxt config properties...

...in component template:
`{{ <a-way-to-access-Nuxt-config>.myObject.myString }}`

or in script:
`this.<a-way-to-access-Nuxt-config>.myObject.myString`

Comment: What about a vuex store or env variables? Otherwise, just make it a global variable on the `window`.

Comment: Here is an example for env variables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67705541/8816585 Here for vuex: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#store-directory

Comment: You should just use the store to achieve what you want.

Comment: I use env and VueX all over the place; well aware of these things. I just don't want to add an action/mutator/getter just for one simple variable that is never set dynamically. I'll move to Pina in the future (no longer use VueX); but that's besides the case.

Comment: "Otherwise, just make it a global variable on the window." if you want something dirty. Having an exported variable from an `/utils/constants.js` directory is also fine that you could import where needed.

Comment: This answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59415226/4378314

Comment: Nothing more than what I've shared above already. And you told us that you know how to use env variables already.

Comment: Yes, I just posted the link for future people; I will use the env way.

Comment: So, do you need anything else here?